# normalization effect on polynomial regression

Tags: regression, normalization

I need to know why input normalization has no effect on polynomial regression. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33523/normalization-across-columns-in-linear-regression) there is a good explanation proving that column normalization does not affect linear regression. But I need to know if it's the the same about Polynomial as well.

p.s. By normalizing I mean, for example, dividing the numbers by maximum in each column.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Polynomial (least squares) regression of data $\newcommand{\y}{\mathrm{y}}\y$ (thought of as an $n$-vector $(y_i)$) against a variable $\newcommand{\x}{\mathrm{x}}\x$ (also an $n$-vector ($x_i)$) uses the variables $\mathrm {1} = \x^0$ (a constant $n$-vector), $\x = \x^1$, $\x^2 = (x_i^2)$, ... and $\x^d = (x_i^d)$.  The fit $\hat \y$ is the projection of $\y$ onto the linear subspace $E$ spanned by these $d+1$ variables.

Suppose now that $\x$ is "normalized" by means of some affine transformation

$$\x^\prime = \alpha \x + \beta.$$

If we recompute the powers of the components $\x^\prime$ we find (after expanding them) that

$$x_i^{\prime k} = (\alpha x_i + \beta)^k = \sum_{j=0}^k c(k,j,\alpha,\beta)x_i^j$$

for some set of numbers $c(k,j,\alpha,\beta)$ (whose values we could write down explicitly, but the details do not matter).  This exhibits every vector $(x_i^{\prime k})$ as a linear combination of the $x^j$, with $j$ varying from $0$ through nothing larger than $k$.  Moreover, provided $\alpha \ne 0$ we can invert this process by noting

$$\x = \frac{1}{\alpha} \x^\prime - \frac{\beta}{\alpha}$$

and similarly expanding the powers of $\x$ in terms of powers of $\x^\prime$.  Therefore the subspace spanned by $\x^\prime$ and its powers through degree $d$ is the same subspace $E$ as that spanned by $\x$ and its powers through degree $d$.  Consequently the normalization does not change the geometric description, whence the fit with both models is identical, *QED*.

---

This argument generalizes, with essentially no change, to the cases where there may be more than one variable (expanded into a multivariate polynomial) as well as other non-polynomial covariates included in the model.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. So, its kind of like proving induction. I am just not clear with the way of normalization in polynomial regression. Do we have to normalize all of the features x^2 x^3 and etc? or just normalizing x would be enough? Because if we normalize x then all other collumns would take effect.

Comment: Exactly. The thread you refer to explains why *separately* normalizing the columns ($x, x^2, \ldots$) makes no difference, so the only issue left to address is whether the normalization of $x$ itself, followed by computation of its powers, makes any difference.  However, the appropriate kind of "normalization" is *standardization,* yet standardization of $x$ does not generally standardize any of its powers. When these considerations become an issue, you really want to look into using *orthogonal polynomials*.

Comment: If we normalize column x by just dividing by the magnitude of maximum, Then I think its power would be also normalized. Am I right or there is a misunderstanding? Thanks whuber.

Comment: That would be correct only when the maximum of $x$ is strictly positive and the minimum of $x$ is no greater in size than the maximum. For instance, when $x=(2,-4)$ your normalized values would be $(1,-2)$. Their squares are $(1,4)$, which is *not* normalized to have a maximum of $1$.

Comment: I found this article, https://www.robertoreif.com/blog/2017/12/16/importance-of-feature-scaling-in-data-modeling-part-1-h8nla and it seems to prove that the scaling does have an impact on the model ?

Comment: @Xiaoshi As far as I can see, he doesn't prove anything.  His different fits in vastly different ranges of variables appear to result from floating point imprecision.  Certainly scaling can affect the imprecision, but--as I *prove* here, mathematically--it has no effect on the model.

Comment: Thank you Whuber, so in practice, the impact still remain big. I also have this notebook : https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/master/01_the_machine_learning_landscape.ipynb entry 27, with or without the scaling the difference is huge.

Comment: @Xiaoshi When scaling makes a difference in these *linear* models, you need to take precautions.  Orthogonal polynomials and careful numerical algorithms (such as a Cholesky decomposition) come into play here.  Search our site for these keywords ("orthogonal polynomial", "Cholesky", "floating point") for much more about these issues.

Comment: It is interesting to see that the practice can be very different from the theory, don't you think so? Thank you again for your explanation.